# Why this build error when trying to attach a UIPopover to a UIButton in a different class?

Tags: objective-c, ios7, uipopovercontroller, uipopover

I am trying to incorporate a bar code scanning api into my ipad app (XCode5, iOS7, Storyboards).  I can't seem to get it to work, although the code is executed.  For the sake of brevity, the complete scan code can be found [here](http://pastebin.com/RuALCG2q).  The problem appears to be in this bit of code from the scan class:

```
 //  define the window
_highlightView = [[UIView alloc] init];
_highlightView.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleTopMargin|UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleLeftMargin|UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleRightMargin|UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleBottomMargin;
_highlightView.layer.borderColor = [UIColor greenColor].CGColor;
_highlightView.layer.borderWidth = 3;
[self.view addSubview:_highlightView];
```

What I *think* I need is a UIPopover with a small UIView in it because nothing appears on my current UIView.  So this is the code I came up with:

```
UIViewController* popoverContent = [[UIViewController alloc] init];
UIView* popoverView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 350, 500)];
popoverView.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithWhite:(CGFloat)1.0 alpha:(CGFloat)1.0];  //  frame color?
popoverContent.view = popoverView;

//resize the popover view shown in the current view to the view's size
popoverContent.preferredContentSize = CGSizeMake(350, 500);

_highlightView = [[UIView alloc] init];
_highlightView.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleTopMargin|UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleLeftMargin|UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleRightMargin|UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleBottomMargin;
_highlightView.layer.borderColor = [UIColor greenColor].CGColor;
_highlightView.layer.borderWidth = 3;
[self.view addSubview:_highlightView];

//  if previous popoverController is still visible... dismiss it
if ([popoverController isPopoverVisible]) {
    [popoverController dismissPopoverAnimated:YES];
}

//create a popover controller
DetailViewController *dvc = [[DetailViewController alloc]init];

popoverController = [[UIPopoverController alloc] initWithContentViewController:popoverContent];

[popoverController presentPopoverFromRect:dvc.oReadBarCode.frame 
                               inView:self.view
             permittedArrowDirections:UIPopoverArrowDirectionUp 
                             animated:YES];
```

However, I'm getting a build error on the last line where I presentPopoverFromRect defining the button to attach the popover to:

> Popovers cannot be presented from a view which does not have a window.'

How do I fix this?  (The idea is to have a UIPopover display the results of the scan).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to cast the frame to a button... plus, your parenthesis seem to be off.

You can simply do this:

```
[popoverController presentPopoverFromRect:dvc.oReadBarCode.frame 
                                   inView:self.view
                 permittedArrowDirections:UIPopoverArrowDirectionUp 
                                 animated:YES];
```

The compiler complaint itself (for future reference) seems to be because you're trying to cast a struct to a pointer, which can't be done.

Comment: What do you do before you get to this code?  To prevent the error, wrap everything in `if (self.view.window) { /* code */ }`

Comment: So all of this code is in `viewDidLoad`?  Move it to `viewWillAppear:` or `viewDidAppear:`.

Comment: A view doesn't have a window until it has been added as a subview to to a view which has a window, or, if it is a view controller's `.view` property, then it won't have a window in `viewDidLoad` (I think), it won't have a window until `viewWillAppear:` or `viewDidAppear:`.

Comment: Neither one gets executed... only -viewDidLoad does.

Comment: What do you mean neither gets executed?  If `viewWillAppear:` or `viewDidAppear:` aren't executed than your view definitely won't have a window... because it's not appearing... and you can't show a popup on a view that's not appeared... which is what the runtime error is telling you.

Comment: Agreed... so how can I do this (display the results of the scan in a textbox in another class)?

Comment: Pass the results of the scan to that class.

Comment: How about if I take all of the "scan code" and put it in the class where I activate it (by user tapping button to do the scan)?  I think that might work, so I'm gonna try it... thank you so much for your time, I really appreciate it.

Comment: That works... however, it stays on that "window"... how can I dismiss that window so my original UIView will show?  (I already tried [self.tabBarController setSelectedIndex: 1], but that didn't do anything.

Comment: This is all very confusing.  I recommend you look at some `UIPopoverController` and `UIPopoverDelegate` tutorials.